# Sum 4 columns in SQL to be used as field on same SQL?

Tags: function, vba, ms-access

I was trying to simulate MS-Excel formula with this Excel fields:
  A - StudyYears
  B - Inflation_Adjusted_Expenditures
  C - AnnualContribution
  D - ContributionIncrease
  E - InterestIncome
  F - RunningBalance

Current Excel cursor location: Column - F, Row - 3
Formula:
  F2+E2+C2+B2

to a MS-Access sql query. The fields where taken from different table. But the field RunningBalance is initially taken from a table tblParameter field StartingBalance. The next RunningBalance record of this query should be adding the four field from previous record.

Since circular reference is a problem in sql query I try creating a function like this.

```
'*************************************************************
' FUNCTION: PREV_RUNNINGBALANCE()
' PURPOSE: Retrieve a value from a field in the previous record.
' PARAMETERS:
'    StartingBalance    - Starting Running Balance which is given
'    RefValue           - ID value
' RETURN: The computed value for the 4 field mention located in the
'          previous record.
' EXAMPLE:
'    =Prev_RunningBalance(StudyYears, 404585)
'**************************************************************
Function Prev_RunningBalance(RefValue As Long, StartingBalance As Long)

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim vRunningBalance As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_PrevRecVal
    strSQL = "Select Inflation_Adjusted_Expenditures, AnnualContribution, InterestIncome, RunningBalance FROM GenerateFundingPlanData WHERE StudyYears = " & RefValue

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rsSQL = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

rsSQL.FindFirst "StudyYears = " & RefValue

If Not rsSQL.NoMatch Then
    'Return 0
    Prev_RunningBalance = 0
End If

If rsSQL.BOF Then
    Prev_RunningBalance = 0
    'Prev_RunningBalance = rsSQL![Inflation_Adjusted_Expenditures] + rsSQL![AnnualContribution] + rsSQL![InterestIncome] + StartingBalance
End If

Do While Not rsSQL.BOF
    ' Move to the previous record.
    rsSQL.MovePrevious
    ' Sum the fields to get the RunningBalance
    ' RunningBalance = Inflation_Adjusted_Expenditures + AnnualContribution + InterestIncome + CurrentRunningBalance
    Prev_RunningBalance = rsSQL![Inflation_Adjusted_Expenditures] + rsSQL![AnnualContribution] + rsSQL![InterestIncome] + rsSQL![RunningBalance]
Loop

'Close Connection
rsSQL.Close

Bye_PrevRecVal:
    Set rsSQL = Nothing    'Deassign all objects.
    Set dbs = Nothing
Exit Function
   Err_PrevRecVal:
Resume Bye_PrevRecVal
End Function
```

After trying the function I am getting a null result. Here's my query sample.

```
SELECT Prev_RunningBalance(a.StudyYears, 404585) as RunningBalance, 
       a.StudyYears FROM AnalysisYears a;
```

Am I using the right function?

Please point me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you can accomplish your goal just by using SQL. Consider the sample table [RevenueByQuarter]:

```
FiscalYear  RevenueQ1   RevenueQ2   RevenueQ3   RevenueQ4
      2010          7           5           4           6
      2011          8           6           6           5
      2012          6           8           8           9
```

The following SQL query in Access...

```
SELECT FiscalYear AS FY, 
    RevenueQ1, RevenueQ2, RevenueQ3, RevenueQ4,
    RevenueQ1+RevenueQ2+RevenueQ3+RevenueQ4 AS RevenueFY,
    (SELECT SUM(RevenueQ1+RevenueQ2+RevenueQ3+RevenueQ4) 
     FROM RevenueByQuarter
     WHERE FiscalYear<=rbq.FiscalYear
    ) AS RunningTotal
FROM RevenueByQuarter rbq;
```

...produces the following result...

```
FY    RevenueQ1   RevenueQ2   RevenueQ3   RevenueQ4   RevenueFY   RunningTotal
2010          7           5           4           6          22             22
2011          8           6           6           5          25             47
2012          6           8           8           9          31             78
```

Comment: Yes! This is IT!..Thanks a bunch for your response Sir Gord. I underestimate the usefulness of less than and equal to.